# React Router isn't rendering the default homepage

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

I am trying to learn Routing in React and have been watching videos on YouTube about it. And, I think I've gotten a basic grasp of its concept. I have imported `{ BrowserRouter }` in **main.jsx** and  `{ Routes, Route }` in **App.jsx**. I've also imported **Home** component in the **App.jsx** but for some reason the **Home** component isn't rendering and is showing the blank page instead.

Here are the code to my files:

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

**Home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Navbar'

const Home = () => {
  return (
      <>
        <main>
          <h1>This is a heading.</h1>
          <Navbar />
        </main>
      </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import "../src/dist/css/styles.css"
import {Home} from "./components/Home"
import {Menu} from "./components/Menu"
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
      <Route path='/menu' element={<Menu />}/>
    </Routes>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Home` component is default exported

```js
export default Home
```

and imported as a named import in `App.jsx`

```js
import { Home } from "./components/Home"
```

Default exports should be default imported:

```js
export default Home
```

```js
import Home from "./components/Home"
```

Named exports should be named imports:

```js
export const Home = () => {
  ...
};
```

```js
import { Home } from "./components/Home"
```

Assuming both `Home` and `Menu` have been default exported from their files they should be default imported in `App.jsx`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import "../src/dist/css/styles.css";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Menu from "./components/Menu";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />}/>
      <Route path='/menu' element={<Menu />}/>
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I didn't know that. Thank you so much! I was stuck in this for at least a day, trying to figure out what I did wrong.